Why did the phrase "bite their fingers" come to indicate regret in the 17th century?
In the 17th century book The Continuation of the Actions, Passages and Occurrences, Both Politike and Polemicall, in the Upper Germanie, 1637, page 57, Publisher: E. P. for N. Butter and N. Bourne, it reads
"...to the vexation of the Spaniards allyes, who were ready to bite their fingers, to see themselves thus deluded."

I've been trying to find information on how the phrase came to be connected to the emotion of regret but could not find specific explanations.

Where did you come up with shame or regret? Vexation is generally the act of troubling or harassing.

Besides many results about the opening scene of Romeo and Juliet, I find one occurrence in the Koran ("when they assemble privately together, they bite their fingers ends out of wrath against you") and one use in a play ("Well now, what do you stare at? ... Don't sigh, and bite your fingers; rouse yourself, man!") This latter seems not to be a reaction, but some indication of idleness, like "twiddling your thumbs." I suspect it means trimming one's fingernails by biting them.

Haven't you ever seen images of people biting their knuckles in anguish?    It is iconographic.https://images.app.goo.gl/VYeTrfL4mxZHWwkPA

https://images.app.goo.gl/FCRRhJ13jCzDKwss9 or https://images.app.goo.gl/17P4miiiqgt4mv2t5

If I recall correctly, the thumb biting in Romeo and Juliet is understood as a sign of aggressive contempt, along the lines of "shooting the bird" today. "Do you bite your thumb at me, sir?" "No sir, I do not bite my thumb at you, sir, but I bite my thumb, sir."

@SvenYargs — In modern-day colloquial AmE: ”Bite me!”

Here's a 19th century French lithograph - the caption says "Image or idiomatic expression: bite your fingers meaning to regret something (to repent)." The French version "mordre les doigts" seems more common than the English, but I've not found anything French that's older than the English version in the OP, so no proof of a French origin.

The best explanation I've seen of the thumb biting in Romeo and Juliet is here: https://stronglang.wordpress.com/2016/11/01/biting-the-fig-the-finger-part-ii/

@StuartF : According to this source, the earliest occurrence of the french expression "s'en mordre les doigts" is dated 1627. Ngram also provides results for the period 1600-1650.

Culturally, the gesture of putting a closed fist to the mouth as if to bite it, or the index finger, is taken as an expression of anxiety:

This is now referred to as "biting one's knuckles" but was earlier referred to as "biting one's fingers".

I am aware that biting one's knuckles is an indication of anxiety which seems to me a more general feeling. I was curious about the act as signifying regret or shame.
